# Icons not shown for controls

Tags: vue.js, less, vite, getuikit

I have a setup where I use `Vue.js` with `Vite` and `UIkit`. When opening the page, the Icons are not shown and the following error can be seen in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) – http://localhost:3000/images/backgrounds/accordion-open.svg
```

This is for the little plus and minus buttons of an accordion element.

Errors like this only come up with 'builtin' icons, i.e. icons that are added to an element by UIkit. If I use `<span uk-icon='question'/>`, the Icon shows up as expected.

My `main.ts` looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import UIkit from 'uikit'
// @ts-ignore
// the ts error: TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons'. '.../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';

// @ts-ignore
// the ts error: This expression is not callable. Type '{}' has no call signatures.
UIkit.use(Icons);

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I haven't changed my `index.html` file from the state that it was in when created.

Edit: It seems that the icons that cannot be found are part of a `less` file. For example, the `accordion.less` file is located at `node_modules/uikit/src/less/components/accordion.less`. Inside that file, a variable `@internal-accordion-open-image` is defined as `"../../images/backgrounds/accordion-open.svg"`, which points to the icon I'm missing (and that cannot be found).

Comment: Yeah that's pretty self-explanatory. The code cannot find `import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';` and that's why it returns a `404` error when you ignore that line, I think.

Comment: The thing is that normal icons work fine. When I remove that line of code, I don't see icons that I create 'normally', i.e. using the `span` directive

Comment: and if you ignore the error and `import Icons`, you can use some icons but not others?

Comment: What about including `script defer` tags on your `index.html` instead of using installed one? The UI Kit website seems to be built  that  way.

Comment: First comment: exactly. Second comment: Tried that but without any success. Looking closer into the problem, it seems that the icons that cannot be found are part of a `.less` file. I'll update my question with the relevant parts.

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem and therefore think this can be closed as a duplicate